# Trigonometric Function Simplification: $T_2 (x) = \cos (2 \arccos x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, chebyshev-polynomials

Let $T_n (x) = \cos (n \arccos x)$ where $x$ is a real number, $x \in [–1, 1]$ and $n$ is a positive integer.

> Show that $$T_2 (x) = 2x^2 – 1.$$

My attempt:

$T_2 (x) = \cos (2 \arccos x)$

Because an identity for $\cos(ab)$ doesn't exist, I do not how to simplify further to get to the solution.

Comment: Those are called Chebyshev polynomials (you might want to google it). Using double angle identities
$T_2=\cos(2\arccos(x))=2\cos^2(\arccos(x))-1=2x^2-1$. Also, notice that $\cos(\arccos(x))=x$ only for $x\in[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. You have
$$
\cos (2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=2\cos^2(x)-1
$$ using $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2 x$ and
$$
\cos (a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)
$$ with $a=b=x$.